# Incorrect json.net serialisation

Tags: generics, dynamic, json.net, dapper

I'm having trouble serialising an object graph using NewtonSoft JsonConvert. Dapper can work in two ways: the `Query(string sql[, object args])` method can return an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` or the generic `Query<T>(string sql[, object args])` method can return `IEnumerable<T>`

It works when I *don't* type the result:

```
stringifiedDynamicData
[{"Record_Key":2,"Factory_Key":7,"EnteredAt":"2018-11-20T09:03:03.374",...}]
```

When I specify a type for the result, results look like this:

```
stringifiedTypedData
[{}]
```

Here's the code that produced the above.

```
IDbConnection syb = new OdbcConnection(connectionstring);
var sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./powerbi.sybase");
var typedData = syb.Query<Status>(sql);
var stringifiedTypedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(typedData); 
Console.WriteLine("stringifiedTypedData");
Console.WriteLine(stringifiedTypedData);
var dynamicData = syb.Query(sql);
var stringifiedDynamicData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicData);
Console.WriteLine("stringifiedDynamicData");
Console.WriteLine(stringifiedDynamicData);
```

Debug inspection of the variable typedData reveals a collection of `Status` objects with one element, as expected. The fields have expected values, so it was a bit of a surprise when `JsonConvert.Deserialize(typedData)` returned `[{}]`

Adding this

```
  var foo = new {
    A = "wibble", B = 6
  };
  IEnumerable<object> bar = from x in new object[] { foo } select x;
  var quux = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bar);
  Console.WriteLine("quux");
  Console.WriteLine(quux);
```

produces the expected result

```
quux
[{"A":"wibble","B":6}]
```

which implies that the data is the problem.
so it isn't some sort of config problem.

The `Status` class has this form.

```
public class Status
{
  float AdtechAmt { get; set; } = -1;
  float AssemblyError { get; set; } = -1;
  string CutToFinish_Avg { get; set; } = "-1";
  ...
}
```

I've just added the default values to see whether that makes a difference (no).

I think I've been using Typescript for too long, it just hit me that these properties are not public.

Comment: show the `Status` class. Are its members `public` *properties* or *fields*

Comment: It's a methodless class with a list of properties that are all either string or float; even the datetime field is a string.

Comment: but you state `The fields have expected values` Json.Net wont serialize fields by default. hence the empty JSON object. It will serialize public properties. ie `public DateTime PropertyName { get; set; }` not `public DateTime FieldName;`

Comment: How do we take this to the chat thingummy?

Comment: [facepalm] :) we've all been there

Comment: @Nkosi although I didn't see it because I was busy putting in default values, you were right about the properties not being public. Interestingly Dapper doesn't care (when reading -- it populated the object) but JsonConvert does. Write up the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Actually the dapper part makes this interesting. Write up a self answer about the dapper seeing/populating the private properties and json.net needing the public properties and that should be enough.

Comment: I think it's worth documenting because the lack of a static compiler error followed by Dapper's successful use of the class for parsing makes the nature of the problem unobvious.

Comment: I am in agreement there. I removed my previous suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally this is Bonehead Programmer Error, with a twist of Typescript.

Both C# and Typescript support properties without a modifier. But while unmodified Typescript properties default to public, in C# they default to protected. As there is no requirement for a class to have any public properties, no static compiler error occurs.

Dapper uses reflection and can see the protected members, and successfully matches them to dataset fields, and populates them. Dapper's successful use of the class for typing results further masks the failure to make the properties public.

The first visible effect is the property-free serialisation. The reason there's no exception is that all the objects (one row in this case) have been successfully serialised, with all the public properties (none) represented in the JSON string.

Comment: Well said, you got my vote. This is definitely something to look out for going forward.